# binding checkbox values if present in another array

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have an API that returns some data.

The data that is returned, is an array of objects (countries - quite a few of them). Also I'm returning the countries associated with the object I'm concerned about

For example

When User A is loaded, my API returns all the countries and the countries associated with User A.

What I want to do therefore, is display all of the countries as checkboxes and then have the ones that User A has as pre-selected.

```
countries - is an array of objects with an id and name
user -  is an object that contains an array of country objects
```

I currently have:

```
<ul class="country-columns">
    <li class="control" v-for="country in countries">
        <label class="checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" v-model="country.id" v-bind:value="permission.id">
          <span>{{ country.name }}</span>
       </label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

But this doesn't take into account the user.countries to select the ones in that array.

Is there an easy way to check if the users countries is in the countries array and check the relevant checkbox?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to have worked:

```
<ul class="country-columns">
    <li class="control" v-for="country in countries">
        <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" v-model="selectedCountries"  v-bind:value="{ id: country.id }">
                <span>{{ country.name }}</span>
        </label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And adding:

```
    data(){
        return{
            selectedCountries: []
        }
    },
```

And another snippet to my custom method, so all good!

Answer (score 0):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    countries: [
      {
        id: 'ua',
        name: 'Ukraine'
      },
      {
        id: 'en',
        name: 'USA'
      },
      {
        id: 'af',
        name: 'Afghanistan'
      }
    ],
    permission: ['ua']
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.10/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h1>countries</h1>
  <ul class="country-columns">
    <li class="control" v-for="country in countries">
      <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" v-model="permission" :value="country.id">
        <span>{{ country.name }}</span>
      </label>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <h1>permission</h1>
  <ul>
    <li class="control" v-for="item in permission">
      {{item}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```